# Will Azure Application Insight show JavaScript errors?

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-application-insights

When using [Azure Application Insight Javascript SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/javascript) are javascript exceptions stored in application insight? Is there a way to capture clientside exceptions with Azure Application Insight?

Comment: yes all javascipt exceptions will go to Appinsights unless you specifically filtered them out to be not sent!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes I can confirm based on our front end Angular app integration with app insights all the exceptions are sent to app insights and the default days its stored in app insights is 90 days (unless you extend this in app insights end).

From the documentation

-Uncaught exceptions in your app (including information on Stack trace)

-Exception details and message accompanying the error

-Line & column number of error

-URL where error was raised

Comment: I would just add a small reminder that most adblockers will block traffic from browsers to application insights.

Comment: good point @bursson have been bitten by this in the past too